# Question on mathematical writing

Tags: soft-question, terminology, advice

I am now writing my graduate thesis, it includes some basics mathematical theorems/propositions.

I got a trouble in writing, more concretely, I do not know when can I state a mathematical claim as a theorem/proposition.

So what is the difference between a proposition and a theorem? When can I state a mathematical claim as a theorem and as a proposition?

I beg your pardon for my stupid question. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: [Closely related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/25639) (if not a duplicate)

Comment: [Maybe](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/lemma-vs-theorem) this can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wiki article summarizing the difference.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem#Terminology

Answer (score 2):

Choosing which results should be labeled *theorem* and which results should be labeled *proposition* or *lemma* is probably part of the work you need to do when writing your thesis.

I suggest you reserve *theorem* for the really important results that you want to highlight, even if you don't prove them in the text.