# What is a "lemma"?

Tags: definition

As per title, what is a "lemma"? How is it different from "theorem"?

ASAIK, I have to prove a self-proposed theorem in my paper. Do I also have to provide the proof for a self-proposed lemma?

Comment: Sure, unless it is obvious.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/lemma-proposition-theorem-which-one-should-we-pick
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/lemma-vs-theorem

Comment: Usually you would prove a lemma before the proof of a theorem if using the result from the lemma makes the theorem's proof more elegant and easier to follow. And you can't state the lemma without proof unless it's a well-established result.

Comment: Another use notion that I have not seen too often is a workhorse lemma. This is a lemma that becomes important because it is needed for lots of theorems.

Comment: I would probably call such a result (the "workhorse lemma" to which Baby Dragon refers) a proposition (or even a theorem). The point to take away here is that while terminology is subjective, any proposed statement must be proved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, they are the same, and yes, you need to prove it. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_%28mathematics%29)

> There is no formal distinction between a lemma and a theorem, only one of intention – see [Theorem terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem#Terminology).